# Could not initialize class com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am developing a web application using Apache Tomcat 7.0 and MySQL database, and of late I am getting a strange exception in ALL MY WEB PAGES....

When I start tomcat and invoke any servlet, an exception stack trace appears first, which is as follows-

```
Aug 02, 2013 1:19:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [GenerateMiniStatement] in context with path    [/IndianNationalBank] threw exception [null] with root cause
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission"     "file.encoding" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:70)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at in.inb.MiniStatement.GenerateMiniStatement.doPost(GenerateMiniStatement.java:64)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

After the first execution, when I try to invoke any servlet the second time, a different exception stack trace appears, which is as follows-

```
Aug 02, 2013 10:54:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [in.inb.Login.LoginServlet] in context with path     [/SomeCompany] threw exception [Could not initialize class     com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at in.inb.Login.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:44)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My guess is that the StringUtils class is not getting access to the file.encoding system property, and becuase of that JVM is not able to properly load the class.

Is my guess right??
I have tried a lot on my own, but unable to get to an answer. I just cannot figure out where the problem lies. Please help me..

Thankyou very much in advance.

Comment: The message `Could not initialize class ...` means that the JVM has already tried and failed to load the named class.  If you restart Tomcat, and try to reproduce this error again, is this the first error you get, or do you get a different error?  If you get a different error, please edit your question to include this error.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the MySQL connector JAR is in the webapp's WEB-INF/lib folder and it actually contains the class (com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils) that the exception says it cannot load.